# react-navigation from react-community is triggering transition with delay

Tags: react-native, redux, transition, react-navigation

Below is the c/p of the code I'm using. 
I'm using `react-community/react-navigation` and redux store to dispatch actions. One of actions is `navigate` from `NavigationActions` which is part of the `react-navigations` package.

As you can see, I've defined a custom transition (simple fade) from one 
screen to another.

The problem is that transition starts with a little bit of delay. Even if I specify `transitionSpec` in the TransitionConfiguration with `Animated.timing` and duration of 100ms it makes no difference.
Also, when navigating back using `back` action from `NavigationActions` it needs about half a second to a second for the scene to become responsive.

Please see attached gif.

- Note #1 - same is happening on a real iPhone6,7.
- Note #2 - same think if I remove `transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration`

It works, but it doesn't feel anything that you can experience in native apps.

```
    // Transition definition
    const FadeTransition = (index, position) => {
        const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
        const opacity = position.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
        });

        return {
            opacity
        };
    };

    // Transition configurator
    const TransitionConfiguration = () => {
        return {
            screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {

                const {position, scene} = sceneProps;
                const {index, route} = scene;

                return FadeTransition(index, position);
            }
        }
    };

    // Active scenes
    const appScenes = {
        Demo: {
            screen: Demo
        },
        Foo: {
            screen: Foo
        }
    };

    // Basic stack navigator
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(appScenes, {
        headerMode: 'none',
        transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration
    });


    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

    this.props.navigate({
        routeName: 'Foo',
        params: {
            transition: 'fade'
        }
    })
```

[image: Preview of the delayed transition]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuCgn.gif)

I would appreciate any advice given.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyTransitionSpec = ({
        duration: 200,

    });
    // Transition configurator
  const TransitionConfiguration = () => {
      return {
          transitionSpec: MyTransitionSpec,

          screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {

              const {position, scene} = sceneProps;
              const {index, route} = scene;

              return FadeTransition(index, position);
          }
      }
  };
```